# Vue this.$refs is undefined during mounted() in vue2-dropzone component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, hook, vue2-dropzone

I am currently trying to make sure the my component`vue2dropzone` is disabled on the initial load of the application, then i began to notice this error in the console when I am trying to make the app mobile responsive.

`[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$refs.vue2dropzone is undefined"`

followed by a

`TypeError: "this.$refs.vue2dropzone is undefined"`

I have a noticed this problem occurring in Vue that seems to be a common issue based on my research, such that when you have `v-if` or `v-else-if` in a component child modifying to show something, the lifecycle will be called again.

A snippet of my code for vue2dropzone component just includes

In my typescript file

```
private mounted() {
  this.$refs.vue2dropzone.disable(); 
}
```

In my vue file

```
    <div v-if="some condition">
     <form>
       <vue2Dropzone 
       ref="vue2dropzone" 
       id="dropzone" 
       class="vue-dropzone"
       ></vue2Dropzone> 
     </form>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="some other condition">
     <form>
       <vue2Dropzone 
       ref="vue2dropzone" 
       id="dropzone" 
       class="vue-dropzone"
       ></vue2Dropzone> 
     </form>
   </div>
```

I am beginning to wonder if the `v-show` being before the first `v-if` doesn't let recall the lifecycle because when I am on the web app, it is disabled but when i switch to mobile responsiveness it shows up as undefined.

Are there any solutions to solve this? I have seen `v-show` being used and `this.$nextTick` but it really didn't help me in my case. Should i put this in another part of the lifecycle besides `mounted()`?

Comment: can you add the code where you declare "target", is it data or props

Comment: @JakeLam its just data, really, i made some changes to be more appropriate. Forgot to include some stuff

Comment: you could try `const self = this; setTimeout(() => { self.$refs.vue2dropzone.disable() ); }, 0)` - just to mess a bit with the `event loop`

Comment: @muka.gergely doesn't affect it either...wow, i think i may have to search for another way then. Thanks though!

Comment: Actually - can you just `console.log(this.$refs)`? If not, then you might have a similar problem to this: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/ref-not-working-on-mounted-on-vue-components/66164

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so I have found a method to resolve this. It seems as the vue app is loading it is quite possible that since the `v-if` is there the condition is not fulfilled until other asynchronous processes have fully loaded which more than likely has past the `mounted` lifecycle.

In order to solve this we can use a native feature of `vue2-dropzone` which is `vdropzone-mounted` so whenever it is being toggled or loads, the function runs.

e.g.

Create a function for using the disable function of `vue2-dropzone`

```
public disableDropZoneBox() {    
  this.$refs.vue2dropzone.disable();
}
```

in vue file

```
 <vue2Dropzone 
 ref="vue2dropzone" 
 id="dropzone" 
 class="vue-dropzone"
 @vdropzone-mounted="disableDropZoneBox"
 ></vue2Dropzone>
```